# activate div after javascript action

Tags: javascript, jquery

On this [page](http://gioventu-new-york.myshopify.com/products/essex-t-storm#) I want the customer to know something has been added to the cart.

I am wondering how to do the following:

After clicking "add to cart", the drawer that is revealed by clicking "my cart" (top right) automatically opens to show the added item.

How would I do this in javascript?

I believe this is the function for the drawer:

```
// Add to cart animation
$(".add-to-cart").click(function(e){

  var elem = $(this);
  elem.prop("disabled", true);

  $("body").on("click", ".checkout", disable);

  e.preventDefault();

  function animate() {

    // $("#cart-animation").show() //

    var addtocartWidth = elem.outerWidth() / 2;
    var addtocartHeight = elem.outerHeight() / 2;

    var addtocartLeft = elem.offset().left + addtocartWidth;
    var addtocartTop = elem.offset().top + addtocartHeight ;

    var buttonAreaWidth = $(".cart-target").outerWidth();
    var buttonAreaHeight = $(".cart-target").outerHeight();

    var buttonAreaLeft = $(".cart-target").offset().left + buttonAreaWidth / 2  - $("#cart-animation").outerWidth() / 2;

    var htmlMargin = $('html').css('margin-top')
    var htmlMarginTrim = parseInt(htmlMargin);

      if (htmlMargin !== 0 ) {
        var buttonAreaTop = $(".cart-target").offset().top + buttonAreaWidth / 2  - htmlMarginTrim - $("#cart-animation").outerHeight() / 2 ;
      } else {
        var buttonAreaTop = $(".cart-target").offset().top + buttonAreaWidth / 2  - $("#cart-animation").outerHeight() / 2 ;

      }

    var path = {
      start: {
        x: addtocartLeft,
        y: addtocartTop,
        angle: 190.012,
        length: 0.2
      },
      end: {
        x: buttonAreaLeft,
        y: buttonAreaTop,
        angle: 90.012,
        length: 0.50
      }
    };

    $('#cart-animation').animate(
      {
        path : new $.path.bezier(path)
      },
      1200,
      function() {
        $(elem).prop("disabled", false)
        $("#cart-animation").fadeOut(500);
        elem.closest('form').submit();
        $("body").off("click", ".checkout", disable);
    }
    );
  }

  animate();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just trigger the button **My Cart** click event, this way you will use an already written piece of code instead of rewriting it yourself:

```
$(".toggle-drawer").trigger("click");
```

hope it helps

Comment: got it. how would i trigger this thought when clicking add to cart, and so it only triggers when the add to cart is successful?

Comment: does the add to cart button return something once the add-action is successfull?

Comment: this i believe Shopify.onCartUpdate = function(cart)